Ping in Bash Parallel
I am trying to ping a range of IP addresses using Bash and generate a CSV file with the results.
My current code is as follows:
CSV_FILE="ping_results.csv"
echo "IP Address,Status" > $CSV_FILE

for i in {1..254}; do (host 10.184.2.$i | grep "name pointer" >/dev/null && echo "10.184.2.$i;Ping_Yes;$(host 10.184.2.$i | awk '{print $5}' | tr -d '.')" >> ping_results.csv || ping 10.184.2.$i -c 1 -w 5 >/dev/null && echo "10.184.2.$i;Ping_Yes;" >> ping_results.csv) &
done

echo "Ping-Ergebnisse wurden in ping_results.csv gespeichert."

The issue I'm facing is that sometimes the code reports that an IP address is pingable, but when I try to ping it manually, it's not actually reachable. I need help understanding why this is happening and how I can improve the code to ensure that the CSV file only contains accurate information about which IP addresses are actually pingable.
Ideally, the CSV file should contain the following information for each IP address:

IP Address
Status (Ping_Yes or Ping_No)
Hostname

My goal is to have a reliable and accurate CSV file that correctly identifies the pingable and non-pingable IP addresses within the specified range. How can I achieve this?

Here is the above code written more legibly:
CSV_FILE="ping_results.csv"
echo "IP Address,Status" > $CSV_FILE

for i in {1..254}; do
    (
        host 10.184.2.$i |
        grep "name pointer" >/dev/null &&
        echo "10.184.2.$i;Ping_Yes;$(host 10.184.2.$i | awk '{print $5}' | tr -d '.')" >> ping_results.csv ||
        ping 10.184.2.$i -c 1 -w 5 >/dev/null &&
        echo "10.184.2.$i;Ping_Yes;" >> ping_results.csv
    ) &
done

echo "Ping-Ergebnisse wurden in ping_results.csv gespeichert."


Have a look at https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/multiping.sh.txt and https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/netfunc.bash.txt

What does "Disclaimer CopyBash" mean?

Sry i send ist a frind to loock over beacause of my gramar dont know think it is kinda messed up

Why did you resolv hosts names if you store only IP in CSV and you build your loop from IP Address?

it currently saves the host names in the CSV or what do you mean? @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub

You may do all this very quickly in two steps: 1: hostnames: . <(for i in {1..254};do host 10.184.2.$i &done| sed -ne 's/^\([0-9]\+\)\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.in-addr.*pointer \(.*\)\./hosts[\1]=\2/p'), this will create an array of hosts you could print by echo ${host[N]:-unknown}, then 2 pings:  for i in 10.184.2.{1..254}; do if ping -nW5 -c1 $i &>/dev/null;then echo $i\;yes ;else echo $i\;no; fi& done | sort -t. -nk 4

it gives me ping yes IP addresses again which only return ping no when I try it manually. but thank you for your efforts so far

Please don't cram most of your code onto 1 line when asking other people to try to understand it. I added a more legible version of your code to the end of your question now.

How I will parallelize multi scan
... And multiple host names resolution.
Note: As you stand for


IP Address
Status (Ping_Yes or Ping_No)
Hostname


My CSV will contain 3 columns: IP Address,Status,Hostname.
csvFile="ping_results.csv"
baseIP=10.184.2

. <(
    for i in {1..254};do
        host $baseIP.$i &
    done |
    sed -ne 's/^\([0-9]\+\)\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.in.*pointer \(.*\)\./hosts[\1]=\2/p'
)

. <(
    for i in {1..254}; do
        if ping -nW5 -c1 $baseIP.$i &>/dev/null; then
            echo ping[$i]=Ping_Yes
        else
            echo ping[$i]=Ping_No
        fi &
    done
)

{
    echo IP Address,Status,Hostname
    for i in ${!ping[@]}; do
        echo $baseIP.$i,${ping[i]},${hosts[i]:-unknown}
    done
} >$csvFile


do you know how to grap also the ipv6?

@georg Try nmap -sP instead!

@georg Anyway YOUR syntax in not only limited to IPV4, but to  24 bits netmask! Try (and read) https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/netfunc.bash.txt

but this is only ip v4 i need ipv6 but i have the problem that i need the hostname and then need the host comand over the host name so it shows me the ip v6

Your question is clearly based on small subnet of fixed 24 bits netmask. My answer is based on your question. My bash netfunc lib do offer full IPV4 support, masklen computation and so. If your have another problem, please post another question, more focused, with as many details you could!

... But keep in mind; Computing IPV4 is playing with 32bits, on a 64bits system, its easy using integer and binary functions. IPV6 is based on 128bits, so under [bash], this will require some arrangements. Not as easy!

ok thank you very mutch
